# When does this click test fail/pass

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am learning to test my react components. I have the following component :

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { firebase } from '../firebase';

export const Checkbox = ({ id, taskDesc }) => {
  const archiveTask = () => {
    firebase.firestore().collection('tasks').doc(id).update({
      archived: true,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="checkbox-holder"
      data-testid="checkbox-action"
      onClick={() => archiveTask()}
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') archiveTask();
      }}
      aria-label={`Mark ${taskDesc} as done?`}
      role="button"
      tabIndex={0}
    >
      <span className="checkbox" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And in the test they are testing the onClick and onKeyDown like this :

```
 it('renders the task checkbox and accepts a onClick', () => {
      const { queryByTestId } = render(
        <Checkbox id="1" taskDesc="Finish this tutorial series!" />
      );
      expect(queryByTestId('checkbox-action')).toBeTruthy();
      fireEvent.click(queryByTestId('checkbox-action'));
    });
```

But he's just clicking it and not checking if the onClick function was called. Is this test even finished or does it need more ?

It is unclear how jest will determine if this click test passes or fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, test will fail if Jest cannot find an element with `data-testid="checkbox-action"`. If Jest finds one then the test passes. So this test is not really useless, but its value could be improved.

To test the click behavior, you have 2 options :

Setup a Checkbox props to provide a click handler, so in your test you can just pass a mocked function (jest.fn()) and then test that the mock has been called. So you have to slightly modify your Checkbox component.

```
it('renders the task checkbox and accepts a onClick', () => {
  const mock = jest.fn();
  const { queryByTestId } = render(
    <Checkbox id="1" taskDesc="Finish this tutorial series!" onClick={mock}/>
  );
    
  expect(queryByTestId('checkbox-action')).toBeTruthy();
  fireEvent.click(queryByTestId('checkbox-action'));
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

...or test a visual consequence of the click on your Checkbox component, which would be "[the React Testing Library way](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles)" (test like a real human : interactions, visual consequences), but it seems that nothing changes visually on click.